# how to create message box in public static void method

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-methods, messagebox

I have a public static method and I would like a message to be displayed if certain values are selected. This is in ASP.NET so adding `using System.Windows.Forms;` causes problems because I am using `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;`. So how do I create a message?

```
public static void UpdateSerialQtyRcvd(int SerNoID, int QtyRcvd)
{
     if (SerNo.QtyRcvd != 1)
     {
         if (SerNo.Reason == "")
         {
             //message
         }
     }
}
```

Javascript behing the code:

```
function UpdateSerialQtyRcvd(sender, SerNoID, QtyRcvd) {
        if (QtyRcvd < 0) {
            alert("Qty Rcvd must be greater than 0");
        }
        else {
            PageMethods.UpdateSerialQtyRcvdUserControl(SerNoID, QtyRcvd, OnUpdateSuccess, OnUpdateFail);
        }
}
```

Calling the web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void UpdateSerialQtyRcvdUserControl(int SerNoID, int QtyRcvd)
{
     JobDeliveryDebrief.UpdateSerialQtyRcvd(SerNoID, QtyRcvd);
}
```

Comment: Have you searched around a bit? I found a couple of post here on SO about that.

Comment: @SuperOli yes I have search around but I couldn't find a solution

Comment: ok, then next time, please list the things you've tried in your post please.

Comment: @SuperOli I did. I said I tried using System.Windows.Forms; but that wasn't working..

Comment: Post the code of the OnUpdateSuccess, OnUpdateFail functions, you can show the alert box there

Answer (score 7):

Add a JavaScript `alert`:

```
clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript(this.GetType(),"MyAlert","<script>alert('Hello');</script>",true);
```

To use `ClientScript` inside a static method pass  the Page object as a parameter to your static method.[Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page(v=vs.110).aspx) is not [static class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).You can not call non static fields inside static method.So you need to pass the page object to your static method as a parameter.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     UpdateSerialQtyRcvd(SerNoID, QtyRcvd,Page);
}

public static void UpdateSerialQtyRcvd(int SerNoID, int QtyRcvd,Page page)
{
    if (SerNo.QtyRcvd != 1)
    {
        if (SerNo.Reason == "")
        {
            page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(),"alert", "<script>alert('Hai');</script>");
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: that causes the error: Error 2496 The name 'ClientScriptManager' does not exist in the current context

Comment: is it really aspx.cs page??

Comment: it is an ascx.cs page

Comment: use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", "<script>alert('Hello.')</script>", false);`

Comment: another error: `Error 2496 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property System.Web.UI.Control.Page.get`  and  `Error 2497 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'object.GetType()'`

Comment: Try doing Page objPage=new Page();and replace page with objPage

Comment: you are getting error because it is a static method

Comment: But if I try call the LoadJavaScript function in my if statement I get the error: Error 47 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Control.Page.get'. I don't want to call the message in Page_Load, it needs to be called my UpdateSerialQtyRcvd function

Comment: This doesn't work. Gives the error invalid web service call. Missing value for parameter page

Answer (score 1):

This method show a message. The `UpdateSerialQtyRcvd` is in a `WebUserControl.ascx` as you want:

```
public static void UpdateSerialQtyRcvd(System.Web.UI.Page pg)
{
     pg.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(pg.GetType(), "alert", "<script>alert('Message');</script>");
}
```

Now you can add your `if-statement` like this:

```
public static void UpdateSerialQtyRcvd(System.Web.UI.Page pg, int qtyRcvd)
{
     if (qtyRcvd != 1)
     {
          //if (SerNo.Reason == "")
          //{
                pg.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(pg.GetType(), "alert", "<script>alert('Message');</script>");
          //}
     }
}
```

Now you can call to `UpdateSerialQtyRcvd` *static method* from every page that has registered the `WebUserControl.ascx`. like this:

`YourPage.aspx`:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl2.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="WebUserControl2" %>
<uc1:WebUserControl2 runat="server" id="WebUserControl2" />
```

`YourPage.aspx.cs`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebUserControl2.UpdateSerialQtyRcvd(this,2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your business method to throw an exception when there is an error condition, like this:

```
public static void UpdateSerialQtyRcvd(int SerNoID, int QtyRcvd)
{
     if (SerNo.QtyRcvd != 1)
     {
         if (SerNo.Reason == "")
         {
             throw new Exception("Your message");
         }
     }
}
```

And handle the error in your javascript function, like this:

```
function OnUpdateFail(result) {
    alert(result.get_message());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Message", "alert('Message');", true);`

Answer (score 0):

You could return desired message from static webmethod. And at the client side alert message using Javascript alert.

change return type of webmethod to string

```
[WebMethod]
public static string UpdateSerialQtyRcvdUserControl(int SerNoID, int QtyRcvd)
{
    return JobDeliveryDebrief.UpdateSerialQtyRcvd(SerNoID, QtyRcvd);
}
```

change return type of UpdateSerialQtyRcvd to string

```
public static void UpdateSerialQtyRcvd(int SerNoID, int QtyRcvd)
{
     if (SerNo.QtyRcvd != 1)
     {
         if (SerNo.Reason == "")
         {
             //message
             return "message";
         }
     }
}
```

In Javascript alert whatever message you get from webmethod in `OnUpdateSuccess function`

```
 function UpdateSerialQtyRcvd(sender, SerNoID, QtyRcvd) {
            if (QtyRcvd < 0) {
                alert("Qty Rcvd must be greater than 0");
            }
            else {
               PageMethods.UpdateSerialQtyRcvdUserControl(SerNoID, QtyRcvd, OnUpdateSuccess, OnUpdateFail);
            }
    }
```